# Number of combinations with restrictions question

Tags: combinatorics

> A group of Contruction students must choose their specialist options
>   from the following list:
>
> Bricklaying, Damp-proofing, Drainage, Flooring, Joinery, Plastering, Roofing.
>
> Each student must choose three options. The available options may be
>   combined with each other in any way, with the exception of the
>   restrictions that Damp-proofing and Drainage together may not be
>   combined with Bricklaying or Plastering because of timetable
>   constraints, and that students choose Joinery must also choose
>   Flooring.
>
> How many possible combinations including Drainage could the students choose from?

Hi guys, I'm preparing for a general examination in England, but got stuck on the question above. In my high school we had very little stastistics lessons in the math / calculus stream, so I'm not quite sure how to even start on this problem.

The one way I could do it is to just simply list all the possible solutions, but I would like to know the faster way to do it.

Do you mind giving me some guidelines on what I need to solve the problem?

Comment: I think that taking all the ways to choose 3 options and subtract the invalid options is the best apporoach this time. The total number of ways to choose 3 options is $7 \choose 3$. Now, counting the invalid options according to restrictions is required, and you're done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drainage is a given, so you need to count the number of pairs of options from the remaining six that can be combined with Drainage. If we ignore the restrictions, there are $\binom62=15$ pairs. The first restriction eliminates two pairs: we cannot pair Damp-proofing with Bricklaying or with Plastering. The second restriction eliminates another four pairs: we cannot pair Joinery with Bricklaying, Damp-proofing, Plastering, or Roofing. There are therefore $15-2-4=9$ acceptable combinations.